# ajax call function with parameters in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am very new to this, what I am trying to do is use ajax to call a controller function from view, this is my controller.

```
public ActionResult EditSiteGetContact(int? id)

    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        using (var db = SiteUtil.NewDb)
        {

            var owner = db.Contacts.Include(o => o.Id).FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id);
            if (owner == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var orgViewModel = OrgViewModel.ToViewModel(owner);
            return View("Edit", orgViewModel);
        }
    }
```

and this is the view where I want to show the data

```
<div class="form-group" id="alanTest">
       <label class="control-label col-md-2">Contact Person</label>
       <div class="col-md-6 form-inline">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Owner.Name, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:200px", type = "text" })
         <img src="~/Images/help-icon.png" class="tooltips" id="ContactPerson_Tooltip" title="lol">
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner.Name)
       </div>
</div>
```

my ajax part:

```
 $("#alanTest").ready(function(){
        var alanURL = "@Url.Action("EditSiteGetContact","Org")";
        var contactId = @Model.Org.ContactId;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:alanURL,

            data:{
                id:contactId
            },
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }      

            });
    });
```

i got "error" message..

Comment: _i got "error" message_ WHAT error message!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, `alert("error");` OP talking about that error message

Comment: @Div, OP needs to explain the error that they get in the browser console

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes, agree with you. but i just clarify.

Comment: Hi by the error I mean the error function in ajax, i didn't have other errors.

Comment: use single quote in alanURL and contactId like var alanURL='@Url.Action("...","...")'

Comment: Open your browser console and inspect the errors and inspect the response in the NetWork tab. And debug your code. Are you hitting the method. What is being returned?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have a System.InvalidOperationException in controller function now, it says "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'KiwiModel.Contact' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Id'."

Comment: Your controller code is throwing and exception! You have not given enough info to solve that, but start by removing `.Include(o => o.Id)` in your query (that makes no sense and will probably solve that exception). And I suggest your check that `var contactId = @Model.Org.ContactId;` is returning the correct value (it should be `var  contactId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Org.ContactId);`

Answer (score 0):

Add [HttpPost] attribute before EditSiteGetContact(int? id).

In the ajax function change
var contactId = @Model.Org.ContactId; to var contactId = "@Model.Org.ContactId";

Please see below code. It may help you.

```
$("#alanTest").ready(function(){
     var alanURL = "@Url.Action("EditSiteGetContact","Org")";
     var contactId = "@Model.Org.ContactId";

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:alanURL,

        data:{
            id:contactId
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }      

        });
});
```